# Get back the record private key serial number of the table modified after calling Trigger?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-trigger

On SQL Server, how can I get back the record private key serial number of the table changed after calling a Trigger?

If I make changes to a table (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), I would need the primary key of the record whose change causes the Trigger to be called. How can I get this in the trigger program?

Transact SQl stored procedure code now (this is OK, but I don't know how to proceed):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TOOLRIGHTS_RECCOUNT 
  ON TOOLRIGHTS FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Update int
   SET @Update = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TOOLRIGHTS)
   UPDATE COUNTINGTABLE SET T_RECORDCOUNT = @Update WHERE T_TABLENAME = 'TOOLRIGHTS'
END
GO
```

Comment: You can access the row**s** (***plural***) that were effected by the DML statement in the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables within the Trigger.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's probably no need to use a trigger, or update counts on another table. For starters, that's more expensive than a `count(*)` or  querying `sys.partitions` to get the row count of a specific table.  [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is a feature available in all editions that returns all changes made to a table since the last check

Comment: I would need the PK sequence number of the modified or created record because I could use the sequence number to retrieve the value of another field.

Comment: Are you saying you want to load data from a related table? What's the purpose of this query then? And why not use a `JOIN` in a SELECT to load that related data when needed? Denormalizing a database schema *doesn't* improve performance unless the schema is *specifically* written for reporting. In which case, no triggers would be used

Comment: If your JOINs are slow, fix them - perhaps there's a missing index? Bad `WHERE` conditions? Denormalizing the schema won't fix the fundamental problems. It will make your database a *lot* harder to maintain and expose you to inconsistent data

Comment: The above code is currently working in a sync process. I would like to develop this procedure so as a first step I would need to know the modified record id (PK) in the trigger procedure if a record is modified. I need help with this.

Comment: You're still saying what you think the solution is, not what the problem is. If you want to sync tables, use change tracking. It's *far* easier to use and manage than hand-written triggers. It *already* keeps track of modified PKs in system tables, including the reason for the modification (inserts, update, delete).

Comment: Synchronization is with an ACCESS2016 database and not within SQL or another identical SQL database. Again, all I can ask is, can you help me get back a modified record ID?

Comment: "I need help" isn't a question we can answer.  We need to know what the problem you're trying to solve is.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a dbo.Users table with a Primary Key (Id) and other columns, you can add a trigger to record the rows that have been changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateCounts]
ON [dbo].[Users] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Log (AffectedId)
    SELECT Inserted.Id FROM Inserted    
    UNION
    SELECT Deleted.Id FROM Deleted
END
GO
```

Rows that are added will have an entry in the Inserted table, rows that are updated will have an entry in both the Inserted and Deleted tables (hence the union to remove duplicates) and deleted rows will have an entry in the Deleted table.

In my example I'm just writing these Ids to a dbo.Logs table, but hopefully you get the idea.